# UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath Not Selected on UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I have a UIViewController that has UIPageViewController's view added to it. That UIPageViewController has a page with a subview that has a UITableView added as a subview.  I am using iOS 6 and the method didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not being called when I click on the cell.  There is a weird "bug" though...  If I turn the page halfway and then come back to the page I was on (without completing the page turn), I'm then able to select the cell.  I assume this has something to do with gesture recognizers, but I can't figure it out.  I tried removing the gesture recognizers from the instantiation of the UIPageViewController, but was unable to get that to work.

I remove the tap gesture recognizers from the UIPageViewController like so, but still the buggy behavior exists...

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in pageViewController.gestureRecognizers) {
    if ([recognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        recognizer.enabled = NO;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions not about the IDE. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be something very simple.  On my UIViewController I had the autoresizingMask set to FlexibleHeight.  Changing it to None for some reason fixed my problem.

```
// self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

// Changed to :

 self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
```

If anyone can shed some light onto the reasons why this is the case, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass  `UIView` with  `UITableView`. let say `myUIView`.

Implement the UITableView delegates in `myUIView`.

Add `myUIView` as a subview of `UIPageControl`.

UITableView delegates in `myUIView` will trigger.

Comment: I finally got back to this task and tried your idea.  Unfortunately, it did not solve my problem.  I still have to do a "half turn", then the delegate methods of the subclass will work. Any other ideas?

Comment: yup..If u want to trigger the UITableView delegate inside the UIPageControl, just pass UIPageControl reference to  UIView (at the time of allocation) and set the UITableView delegate as UIPageControl reference object. thats it :)